# Redirect Django feed to FeedBurner

Tags: django, feedburner

I have an Atom feed set up according to http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/ which means I have something like

```
(r'^feeds/(?P<url>.*)/$', 'django.contrib.syndication.views.feed', {'feed_dict': feeds})
```

in my `urls.py` and something like

```
class MyFeed(Feed):
    ...
```

in my `feeds.py`.

I'd like to [redirect traffic](http://www.google.com/support/feedburner/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78464) from this feed to the FeedBurner. I have to do this in Django as there is no mod_rewrite on my server.

---

I guess I should change `urls.py` entry to

```
(r'^feeds/(?P<url>.*)/$', 'feeds.redirect', {'feed_dict': feeds})
```

and supplement `feeds.py` with

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def redirect(request, **kwargs):
    if request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == 'FeedBurner':
        view = 'django.contrib.syndication.views.feed'
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(view, kwargs=kwargs))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://feeds2.feedburner.com/MyFeed')
```

but it doesn't seem to work as I get the following error (you have to change `==` to `!=` to see this):

> NoReverseMatch at /feeds/myfeed/
>
> Reverse for '`<function feed at 0x16a2430>`' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'url': u'myfeed', 'feed_dict': {'myfeed': `<class 'feeds.MyFeed'>`}}' not found.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you removed the `django.contrib.syndication.views.feed` reference from your urls.py.

Instead of using reverse to redirect to a different URL, try just returning the feed from your existing view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.syndication.views import feed

def redirect(request, **kwargs):
    if request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].startswith('FeedBurner'):
        return feed(request, **kwargs)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://feeds2.feedburner.com/MyFeed')
```

Comment: The user agent of FeedBurner contains a version number and a URL. Your check should be request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].startswith('FeedBurner').

Comment: i just copied the check from the question... but i've updated the answer with the correct check

Answer (score 0):

Well, i guess it helps someone, who wonders what is the correct way of doing it in django 1.3+

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from feeds import MyFeed #your feed class, check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/syndication/

def burnedFeed(request, **kwargs):
    if request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].startswith('FeedBurner'):
        feed = MyFeed()
        return feed(request)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://feeds2.feedburner.com/MyFeedName')
```